# Why jquery hover doesn't works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make some text editor, where I can send some Ajax requests, when word is hovered. There's code in the page.

```
<div class="word_split" contenteditable="true">Don't break my heart.</div>
```

There's jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".word_split").hover(function () {
        if ($(".word_split").children().length == 0) {
            $(".word_split").lettering('words');
        }
        else {
            $(".word_split").children().lettering('words');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".word_split span").hover(function () {
        //There'll be requests
        alert("sadfsdafsa");
    });
});
```

And CSS.

```
.word_split span:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Lettering only puts every word in target tag in span and gives in this case class names like word1, word2 and e.t.c.

The question is that second jquery function doesn't work, but Css does. I don't understand why and how I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind what I said, you [can](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready/) use it more than once but it's not really a good practise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<span>`s don't exist on page load, so the event is not hooked up to anything. You should use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a `'mouseover'` event so that elements created in future will get the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".word_split").on('mouseover', 'span', function () {
        //There'll be requests
        alert("sadfsdafsa");
    });
});
```

Another issue I saw is that when you run this, each time you hover over the text, it will trigger the event handler and split the words up again, so you end up with loads of empty spans - which will also trigger requests. If possible, you are probably best off just running the `lettering()` directly in the `document` ready, rather than on hover:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".word_split").children().length == 0) {
        $(".word_split").lettering('words');
    }
    else {
        $(".word_split").children().lettering('words');
    }

    $(".word_split").on('mouseover', 'span', function () {
        //There'll be requests
        alert("sadfsdafsa");
    });
});
```

[**Working JsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qxcmgcvg/)

And as noted, it should ideally all really go into one `$(document).ready` call - it is more efficient and you have more control over the order code is executed in if nothing else.

Comment: Your variant is the best approach. Cause in Ragnar's answer command applies a lot. And in this case it works in different $(document).ready calls.

Answer (score 2):

You must use .on() because on page load you don't have span elements:

```
<div class="word_split" contenteditable="true">Don't break my heart.</div>
```

...
(I inject lettering function in my code)

```
(function($){
    function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
        var text = t.text()
        , a = text.split(splitter)
        , inject = '';
        if (a.length) {
            $(a).each(function(i, item) {
                inject += '<span class="'+klass+(i+1)+'" aria-hidden="true">'+item+'</span>'+after;
            });
            t.attr('aria-label',text)
            .empty()
            .append(inject)

        }
    }


    var methods = {
        init : function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                injector($(this), '', 'char', '');
            });

        },

        words : function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                injector($(this), ' ', 'word', ' ');
            });

        },

        lines : function() {

            return this.each(function() {
                var r = "eefec303079ad17405c889e092e105b0";
                // Because it's hard to split a <br/> tag consistently across browsers,
                // (*ahem* IE *ahem*), we replace all <br/> instances with an md5 hash
                // (of the word "split").  If you're trying to use this plugin on that
                // md5 hash string, it will fail because you're being ridiculous.
                injector($(this).children("br").replaceWith(r).end(), r, 'line', '');
            });

        }
    };

    $.fn.lettering = function( method ) {
        // Method calling logic
        if ( method && methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( method === 'letters' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, [].slice.call( arguments, 0 ) ); // always pass an array
        }
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lettering' );
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".word_split").hover(function () {
        if ($(".word_split").children().length == 0) {

            $(".word_split").lettering('words');
        }
        else {
            $(".word_split").children().lettering('words');
        }
    });

    $(".word_split").on('mouseover', 'span', function () {

        alert("i am hover!!");
    });
});
```

---

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjnbxyh3/)

Comment: Lettering puts every word in span

Comment: "Lettering only puts every word in target tag in span" You don't need to add an span.

Comment: yes, sorry in first time i misunderstood - but in fiddle <div> is correct

Comment: Yes, in fiddle everything is correct. But you don't need to create own lettering function. I took it from lettering.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the second function after lettering because when the second function is called the span element doesn't exists.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ($(".word_split").children().length == 0) {
       $(".word_split").lettering('words');
   }
   else {
       $(".word_split").children().lettering('words');
   }
   $(".word_split span").hover(function () {
       //There'll be requests
       alert("sadfsdafsa");
   });
 });
```

I think you need to do this one time only and not in every hover.